# AWS Lambda Java runtime: Home directory does not exist?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

When running Java code in the AWS Lambda Java runtime (Java 11 or Java 8), it seems that the [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) `user.home` is set, but the directory does not seem to exist (according to [`File.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#exists())). Is this expected or a bug?

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```
File userHome = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
LOG.info("user.home: {} exists: {} ", userHome, userHome.exists());

File javaIoTmpdir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
LOG.info("java.io.tmpdir: {} exists: {} ", javaIoTmpdir, javaIoTmpdir.exists());
```

And here is the corresponding log output:

```
user.home: /home/sbx_user1051 exists: false 
java.io.tmpdir: /tmp exists: true
```

It seems somewhat surprising that `user.home` system property would be set to point to a directory that does not exist. Or am I overlooking something obvious here?

Background: I ran into this problem while trying to use a third-party library that does not work correctly in the case where the `user.home` directory does not exist.

Comment: I can imagine that being by design. AWS Lambda is meant to run "context-less" code, as far as I understand, so there's no point in having something like a "home directory". And I guess the Java spec requires `user.home` to be set, even when it doesn't point to a directory that exists.

Comment: Even if the home directory exists, it would have no volume attached to it.